# Session variable defaults to the last one set

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I know this is bad practice the way I am doing it, still I would like to understand why this is not working.

I have 3 `onclick` methods for different grids in Javascript:

```
    $('body').on('click', '#clinician-appointments>tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
         var id = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
         @{Session["Clinician"] = "opa"};
         location.href = "@Url.Action("Summary", "Patient")" + "/" + id;
             });

    $('body').on('click', '#clinician-current-admissions>tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
        location.href = "@Url.Action("Summary", "Patient")" + "/" + id;
       @{Session["Clinician"] = "ca"};
            });

    $('body').on('click', '#clinician-diagnostics>tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
        location.href = "@Url.Action("Summary", "Patient")" + "/" + id;
        @{Session["Clinician"] = "diag"};
            });
```

However when I call the session in C# it is always "diag", the last one assigned.

So as they are in different events the other ones will be missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a Razor page, when you do:

```
@{Session["Clinician"] = "diag"};
```

this will execute before the page is rendered in the browser. So as the page loads, the following are executed *server-side* in sequence:

```
@{Session["Clinician"] = "opa"};
@{Session["Clinician"] = "ca"};
@{Session["Clinician"] = "diag"};
```

Contrary to your expectations, they are *not* being executed on clicking the respective grid, as that is a pure client-side interactive event.

I suggest you replace "@{Session["Clinician"] = "..."};" with an ajax call to a new controller action that sets the string in the session. So something like this:

JavaScript:

```
function Session()
{
}

Session.SetString = function (key, value)
{
    $.post("/Home/SessionString?key=" + key + "&value=" + value);
};

Session.GetString = function (key, successCallback)
{
    $.get("/Home/SessionString?key=" + key, null, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { successCallback(data) });
};

$('body').on('click', '#clinician-appointments>tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
     var id = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
     Session.SetString("Clinician", "opa");
     location.href = "@Url.Action("Summary", "Patient")" + "/" + id;
});
```

Controller (for .NET Core):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a value in the user's session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key for the value.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SessionString(string key, string value)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
        return new JsonResult(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a value from the user's session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key for the value.</param>
    /// <returns>The value.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SessionString(string key)
    {
        string value = HttpContext.Session.GetString(key);
        return new JsonResult(value);
    }
}
```